# Upvotes for most popular question does not add up correctly

Tags: support, reputation

The [most popular question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/545329/how-do-i-make-a-machine-blank-screen-for-a-period-of-time-as-a-penalty-if-ce) has about 1200 plus votes but the person who asked it only has 3151 points . Shouldnt he have around 1200*5 = 6000 plus points ???. The maths doesnt add up

What is happening

Comment: [rep cap](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Help Center:](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day[..]  Only bounty awards and accepted answers are not subject to the daily reputation limit.